# writing of user's input with loop into text file

Tags: shell-script, awk

```
echo -n "##### STATIONS? #######"
read station
awk -v input="$station" '
BEGIN {
        n = split(tolower(input), user)
        fmt = "%-4s\n"
}
    {print}
    /stab_site clear/ {
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
            printf fmt, "stab_site" user[i]
        exit
    }
' ./data > data_2
```

Let assume user's input: `ankr ista` for stations. After the execution of codes, in data file, after the "`stab_site clear`" line, user's input is written as follows;

```
stab_siteankr
stab_siteista
```

I need to give one space between "stab_site" and "station_ids" in the codes. I also need to write the lines after one space from the beginning of the line as follow;

```
stab_site ankr
stab_site ista
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let split

```
printf fmt, "stab_site" user[i]
```

- `"stab_site" user[i]` will make `stab_sitenakr` as there is no space after site
- `printf fmt, "stab_site" user[i]` is turn to
- `print "%-4s\n" , stab_sitenakr` which print left aligned `stab_sitenakr`

maybe you are looking for

```
printf fmt, "stab_site " user[i]
```

or (as per OP's request)

```
printf " %s %s\n", "stab_site", user[i]
```